# Problem with duplicate dependencies with npm-install

Tags: npm, dependencies, npm-install

I have a very simple setup (https://github.com/Nodeocrat/dupe-deps) where `project` depends on `express` and `depA`, where `depA` is a dependency defined by relative file path. `depA` depends only on `express`. When I run `npm install` in `project`, I get `express` (and all of express's dependencies) duplicated in both `project/node_modules/` and `project/node_module/depa/node_modules/`.

Why does this happen? Is this *supposed* to happen when installing a local dependency?

**Update:**
When `depA` is instead changed to a git repo, everything works fine. So this just seems to be an issue with dependencies defined locally. Any info on why this happens would interesting to hear though.